# Magento 2, adding desc and asec to sorter seletion

Tags: magento2, sorting, category-listing

The requirement is displaying the `asce` and `desc` for each option in `<select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">` . Like `price asce`, `price desc` . I changed the default code to below, option works but how trigger asce or desc while choosing the option?

in my custom theme `templates/product/list/toolbar/sorter.phtml`

```
<select id="sorter" data-role="sorter" class="sorter-options">
        <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableOrders() as $_key => $_order): ?>
            <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $_key; ?>"
                <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"
                <?php endif; ?>
            >

                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?> <a title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" href="#" class="action sorter-action sort-desc"
                                                                 data-role="direction-switcher" data-value="asc">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo __('Set Ascending Direction') ?></span>
                </a>

            <option value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
            echo $_key; ?>"
                <?php if ($block->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?>
                    selected="selected"
                <?php endif; ?>
            >
                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__($_order)) ?> <a title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Set Descending Direction') ?>" href="#" class="action sorter-action sort-asc"
                                                                 data-role="direction-switcher" data-value="desc">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                        echo __('Set Descending Direction') ?></span>
                </a>

            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how trigger asce or desc at the same time?"

Comment: Okey, based on this requirement there are "price asc" and "price desc" as options. So selecting the "price asc", must consider 1-price 2-asce... that's what I mean at the same time ;) Feel free to edit the question if you can say it more clear what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have to override the **getAvailableOrder()** and **setCollection()**
function of the Magento

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php
```

Below is the code which may help you.

```
public function aroundGetAvailableOrders(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject, \Closure $proceed)
{
    $returnValue = $proceed();
    unset($returnValue['price']);
    $returnValue['priceDesc'] = 'price - high to low';
    $returnValue['priceAsc'] = 'price - low to high';
    return $returnValue;
}

public function aroundSetCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject, \Closure $proceed, $collection)
{
    $returnValue = $proceed($collection);
    if ($subject->getCurrentOrder() == 'priceHighToLow') {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setOrder('price', 'ASC');
        $collection->load();
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try and update here,tnx

Comment: Just you need to edit the aroundSetCollection based on what you have defined in aroundGetAvailableOrders ...

Comment: I don't understand your solution. Can you explain it in more detail?